setting custom typescript server for Next.js14
currently, i am trying to set up a custom TypeScript server for Next.js. i've been stuck on this for a day, and the official guide only covers JavaScript. i try this "scripts": {
"dev": "ts-node server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ts-node --transpile-only server.ts",
"lint": "next lint",
"postinstall": "prisma generate"
},   but keep getting error on production bundle that doesnt exist when i use javascript
Can someone show me the scripts for dev mode, building, and production? thank you.

This might help you https://dev.to/deiucanta/custom-nextjs-server-with-typescript-3mdb
